# Unhandled promise rejection in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm trying to make a `DELETE` call and I'm implementing the function below. I understand that in a promise, there needs to be a "resolve" and a "reject" state, but I'm getting an unhandled promise rejection error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object]

I don't really like using conditional statements inside a promise because it gets messy, but what I'm trying to do here is to check if the organization is verified, and if it is, a delete operation should not occur and will reject.

```
function deleteOrg(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // A helper function that returns an 'org' object
        findById(id)
        .then((orgObject) => {
            if (orgObject.verified_at !== null) {
                throw new Error(422, 'Unable to delete organization')
            }

            //Organization is not verified, so proceed to delete
            new Organization().where({'id': id}).destroy()
            .then(() => {
                return resolve() //return 200 upon deletion
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return reject(new Error(500, 'Unable to delete organization'))
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            const m = `Unable to delete organization: ${err.message}`
            return reject(new Error(500, m))
        })
    })
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm handling the rejection inside the `if` wrong.

Comment: Avoid the [Promise constructor antipattern!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)

Comment: As @JaromandaX said! Since `findById` returns a `Promise` why do you even need the `Promise` constructor? You could just `then` it's result.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for sharing my links :-)

Comment: Is there any kind of stack trace from the unhandled rejection?

Comment: @Bergi - I've seen it so often I had to :p

Comment: Are you handling the `deleteOrg` rejection? `deleteOrg(id).then(() => {}).catch(() => {})`. That should suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Creating promises inside promise constructors is a [known anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Try modularizing your promises into separate functions instead:

```
function deleteOrg(id) {

  const verifyOrg = (orgObject) => {
    if (orgObject.verified_at !== null) {
      throw new Error(422, 'Unable to delete organization')
    }
  };

  const destroyOrg = () => new Organization().where({
    'id': id
  }).destroy();

  return findById(id)
    .then(verifyOrg)
    .then(destroyOrg);
}
```

Where you can let the errors propagate through the promise chain and handle them outside:

```
deleteOrg(id)
  .catch((err) => {
    const m = `Unable to delete organization: ${err.message}`;
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: This looks like a much cleaner way to go about promises. However, I'm still getting the same unhandled promise rejection error.

Answer (score 0):

as findById and .destroy return Promises, there is no need for the Promsie constructor

Your code is then simplified to

```
function deleteOrg(id) {
    return findById(id)
    .then((orgObject) => {
        if (orgObject.verified_at !== null) {
            throw new Error(422, 'Unable to delete organization')
        }

        //Organization is not verified, so proceed to delete
        return new Organization().where({'id': id}).destroy()
        .catch((err) => {
            throw (new Error(500, `Unable to delete organization: ${err.message}`));
        });
    });    
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to work - I'm still getting the same unhandled promise rejection error :/

Comment: how are you calling deleteOrg?

Comment: it turns out I was calling deleteOrg wrong. Thanks for helping me trace through it.

Answer (score 0):

```
original method() => {
             try{ //code to raise the exceptio


            })
```

;

The best way to handle is to use `expect` It can be matched with an exception. A sample test

```
  someMock.mockFunc(() => {
          throw new Error("Something");
        });

   test('MockFunc in error', () => {
     return expect(orginalCall()).rejects.toMatch('Something');
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into the same kind of problem because I failed to add the `return` keyword to the calling method(deleteOrg(id)). After adding `return` UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning gone away.

```
function deleteOrg(id)
{
// actually returns a promise 
}

return deleteOrg.then((result) => { 
   //code logic after deleting the record// 
});
```